# Django: How to make this GET request with a hyperlink?

Tags: django, get, request

So if I want a user's name to link to it's profile, I want the link to contain the user's first name and last name in GET form...Do I just hard-code this into the link, or is there a more elegant way of coding this? Here is hard-coded:

```
<p>
<li role="presentation"  class="active"><a href="{% url 'profile' %}?fname={{ fname }}&lname={{ lname }}">{{ user.fname }}</a>
</li>
</p>
```

Comment: That's the way, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the more elegant way would be to set up a route that takes, for example, the user's ID (pk) and use either a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) set up for the User model or a function view that accepts the ID and retrieves the relevant user. Passing in the first and last name directly means you need to query on both of them (after pulling them out of the querystring) rather than simply querying on the ID as it's passed to you (after the framework politely [checks its type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions), provided you've set up the route correctly).

So your route would look something like `url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')` and your template tag would look something like `{% url 'profile' user.id %}`.